# Is there a way to change the owner of a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I've been learning around here for a long time and I thank everyone who helps. This time I have a question that I don't quite know how to approach and I hope you can help me understand. I have a smart contract contractA and another contractB and I want to know if it is possible to call a function of contractA from contractB without being the owner. ContractA is an example I found on the internet and contractB is the one I've made to test but I'm not able to understand and make the condition of owner == msg.sender happen

this is contratA

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract contractA{

    string data;
    uint public blocknumber;
    address public owner;

    constructor() payable {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function set_data(string memory _data) public {
        require(owner == msg.sender,"You are not the owner of the contract");
        data = _data;
        blocknumber = block.number;
    }
}
```

and this is my contractB
I have tried to call the function set_data from contractA but I don't quite understand why it can't be done.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "./blockchain_tour.sol";

contract contracB {
 
    contractA public new;
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _contractAddress) {
        new = contractA(_contractAddress);
        owner = new.owner();
    }

    function callSetData(string memory _data) public {
    
    new.set_data(_data);
    }
}
```

I always get the message that I am not the owner of the contract. If anyone has any idea or if I'm doing it wrong or it can't be done, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

in `contractB`s constructor you are setting owner

```
constructor(address _contractAddress) {
    new = contractA(_contractAddress);
    owner = new.owner();
}
```

this `owner` variable is set in Solidity, to allow only the owner to call certain functions.

When you call `contractA`s `setData` function, `msg.sender` is always the address that deployed the `contractB` (since you are calling this from contractB) and i do not think that you can modify the `msg.sender`.  so by changing `owner = new.owner()` you have no effect on `msg.sender`.

you could define a `setOwnership` function in `contractA`

```
 function setOwnership(address newOwner) private {
        owner = payable(newOwner);
    }
```

then you call this function inside `setData`

```
function set_data(string memory _data) public {
    owner=setOwnership(msg.sender);
    require(owner == msg.sender,"You are not the owner of the contract");
    data = _data;
    blocknumber = block.number;
}
```

this will solve your problem, your code will execute but I do not think that it is something logical and secure. you could maybe create a `whiteList` mapping,

```
mapping(address => bool) private whiteList;
```

and allow only addresses in this mapping call the `setData` function. you can also add the deployer of `contractA` to this mapping inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I already know how to do that, but I don't think I made it clear or I didn't express myself well, this is a proof of concept for security. the example of contractA should not be modified. my question is if it is possible from contractB to modify contractA

Comment: `contractA` is already deployed. the only thing you can modify is the public state variables